# Get Weight From Weigh Bridge Machine Using Serial Port in C#

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, serial-port

i am develop application for getting weight from weigh Bridge machine using C#.Net.i am trying lot of ways but,doesn't read correct data format weight from weigh bridge machine.i am getting ouput like `?x???????x?x?x??x???x??x???x???x?` continuously get from serial port.i want to get weight from weigh bridge machine my code is listed below:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO.Ports;
using System.IO;

namespace SerialPortTest
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        String a = "";

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        serialPort1 = new SerialPort("COM1", 9600, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);
         serialPort1.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(serialPort1_DataReceived);

        if (serialPort1.IsOpen == false)
        {
            serialPort1.Open();
        }
        timer1.Start();
        button1.Enabled = false;
        button2.Enabled = true;
        }

        private void serialPort1_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            a = a + serialPort1.ReadExisting();
        }

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (a.Length != 0)
            {
                textBox1.AppendText(a);
                a = "";
            }
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (serialPort1.IsOpen == true)
            {
                serialPort1.Close();
                button2.Enabled = false;
                button1.Enabled = true;
            }
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (serialPort1.IsOpen == true)
            {
                button1.Enabled = false;
                button2.Enabled = true;
            }
            else
            {
                button1.Enabled = true;
                button2.Enabled = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

my code is append text from serial port data to textbox but,it's shows only like `?xxx?xxxx?xxxx?`

can any one help me how to get weight from serial port using c#

Thanks For Reading My Post!

Comment: You need to know (find out) how it is written first. Apparently not as ASCII.

Comment: @HenkHolterman did u say convert serial port data to ascii value?

Comment: I'm saying there are many ways the bridge could encode the information. You need specs and docs.

Comment: @HenkHolterman can u post any link for decode information weigh bridge weight?

Comment: No, I've got no idea what your equipment is.

Comment: @Dinesh: Looks like wrong connection settings (baud rate, parity, etc). Check them.

Comment: @Dennis can u post the serial port settings configuration?

Comment: @Dinesh: no, because I haven't any manual for your device. You should get info about connection settings from there.

Answer (score 3):

You are using ReadExisting(), that method tries to convert the bytes received by the port into a string.  You'll get a question mark if that conversion fails.  The default Encoding is ASCII, a byte value between 128 and 255 is not an ASCII character and thus produces a ?

Several possible reasons, roughly in order of likelihood:

- Using the wrong baud rate, in particular guessing too high.
- The device might be sending binary data, not strings.  Which requires using Read() instead of ReadExisting and decoding the binary data.
- Electrical noise picked up by a long cable that isn't shielded well enough.  Easy to eliminate as a possible reason by disconnecting the cable at the bridge end.  If that stops the data then it isn't likely to be noise.

Be sure to thoroughly read the manual.  Contact the vendor of the device if you don't have one or can't make sense of it.

Answer (score 0):

This code will be reading weightbridge continuously in background. Be sure to connect the pc with serial port. Also in design page Form1.cs[Design] you need to add Serial port from the toolbox. This code works for me, I hope it works for you too...

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    //Initialize the port and background Worker
    private SerialPort port;
    private BackgroundWorker backgroundWorker_Indicator;

public Form1()
{
backgroundWorker_Indicator = new BackgroundWorker();
backgroundWorker_Indicator.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
backgroundWorker_Indicator.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(Indicator_DoWork);
//set the port according to your requirement.
port = new SerialPort("COMM2", 2400, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);
port.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(this.Indicator_DataReceived);
}

//button which starts the method. You can also put the method in Form1_Load() 
private void SerialPortButton(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
StartStopIndicator();
}

 private void StartStopIndicator()
 {
     try
     {
         port.Open();
         backgroundWorker_Indicator.RunWorkerAsync();

     }catch (Exception ea)
         {
         MessageBox.Show("13 "+ea.Message);
         }
  }
  // Not a button. Just a methood.
  private void Indicator_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {

    }
private void Indicator_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            string str = StripNonNumeric(port.ReadLine());
            UpdateWeightOnUI(str);
        }
        catch (Exception eb)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("12"+eb.Message);
        }
    }
private void UpdateWeightOnUI(string Weight)
    {
        try
        {
            // A label named weightLabel from the toolbox. This will keep updating on weight change automatically
            if (weightLabel.InvokeRequired)
            {
                this.Invoke((Delegate)new Form1.SetTextCallBack(this.UpdateWeightOnUI), (object)Weight);
            }
            else
            {
                weightLabel.Text = Weight;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ec)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("11"+ec.Message);
        }
    }
// This method will remove all other things except the integers 
private string StripNonNumeric(string original)
    {
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (char c in original)
        {
            if (char.IsDigit(c))
                stringBuilder.Append(c);
        }
        return stringBuilder.ToString();
    }
private delegate void SetTextCallBack(string text);
```